jQuery element controlled by varied clicks
Description
I have an offscreen element that contains theming and layout options. Additionally I have a checkbox slider element that allows the offscreen element to be shown. I am using jquery to handle and monitor click events.
Goals

Make the offscreen element show/hide when the checkbox slider is clicked.
Checkbox slider moves left/right when clicked for a visual display.
Make the offscreen element automatically hide if the user clicks anywhere outside of the offscreen element.
If user clicks outside of offscreen element, or on the checkbox slider (with offscreen element displayed), the offscreen element not only hides, but also the checkbox slider reverts to its default off position.

HTML
Offscreen Element
    <!-- Offscreen -->
    <div id="offscreen-container" class="panel">
      <h2>Layouts</h2>
      <select name="layout-toggle" id="layout-toggle" class="dropdown">
        <optgroup label="Default Layout Styles">
          <optgroup label="--Default Border Style">
            <hr>
            <option value="normal.square.border_full.page_full" id="layout-1">Full - Square</option>
          </optgroup>
          <hr>
          <optgroup label="--Alternate Border Style">
            <hr>
            <option value="normal.square.border_alt.page_full" id="layout-7">Full - Square</option>
          </optgroup>
        </optgroup>
        <option disabled="true"></option>
        <hr>
        <optgroup label="Reversed Layout Styles">
          <optgroup label="--Default Border Style">
            <hr>
            <option value="reversed.square.border_full.page_full" id="layout-13">Full - Square</option>
          </optgroup>
          <hr>
          <optgroup label="--Alternate Border Style">
            <hr>
            <option value="reversed.square.border_alt.page_full" id="layout-19">Full - Square</option>
          </optgroup>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
      <h2>Themes</h2>
      <select name="theme-toggle" id="theme-toggle" class="dropdown">
        <option value="jldn" id="jldn">JLDN</option>
        <option value="dark" id="dark">Dark</option>
        <option value="light" id="light">Light</option>
      </select>
      {% yield offscreen %}
    </div>
    <!-- /Offscreen -->

Checkbox Slider
    <!-- footer -->
    <footer class="panel">
      {% yield footer %}
      <label class="switch tooltip top" data-tooltip="Themes &amp; Layouts">
        <input id="offscreen-toggle" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer -->

jQuery
Checkbox Slider click event
        var offscreenToggle = $('#offscreen-toggle');
        var offscreenContainer = $('#offscreen-container');

        offscreenToggle.on('click', () => {
          let rInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
          
          switch (rInt) {
            default:
            case 1:
              offscreenContainer.toggle(1000);
              break;
            case 2:
              offscreenContainer.fadeToggle(1000);
              break;
            case 3:
              offscreenContainer.slideToggle(1000);
              break;
          }
        });

Autohide click event
      $(document).on('click', (e) => {
        let t = $(e.target);

        if (!t.is('#offscreen-container,#offscreen-container *')) {
          offscreenContainer.hide();
        }
      });

What I have tried
I have made both goals work, separately. However, when I put in script to do both, it fails. Basically, I can do one or the other.
The checkbox slider click event works to perfection. When I add the autohide click event, things get a little wonky. For instance, the checkbox slider functions visually, but the offscreen element is never revealed. If I set the offscreen element to be shown upon page load, the autohide click event functions, but doesn't revert the checkbox slider to the off position.
I have even tried combining the checkbox slider click event with the autohide click event in an 'if' condition to guide event processing... still it doesn't work. Not sure what to do here.
Update

jQuery
      $(document).on('click', (e) => {
        let t = $(e.target);

        // outside of offscreen container, but not the switch
        if (!t.is('#offscreen-container,#offscreen-container *') && !t.is('#offscreen-toggle')) {
          offscreenContainer.hide(1000);
          offscreenToggle.prop('checked', false);
        } else

        // outside of offscreen container, specifically the switch
        if (!t.is('#offscreen-container,#offscreen-container *') && t.is('#offscreen-toggle')) {
          let rInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
          
          switch (rInt) {
            default:
            case 1:
              offscreenContainer.toggle(1000);
              break;
            case 2:
              offscreenContainer.fadeToggle(1000);
              break;
            case 3:
              offscreenContainer.slideToggle(1000);
              break;
          }
        }
      });

Video of issue
Screen Recording
Issue
Notice in the video that when I use the switch to open the offscreen element, the element is displayed and the switch colors change (indicating that the switch is 'on'). When I click anywhere on the page, the offscreen element hides and the switch resets to its 'off' configuration. This behavior is correct.
However, if I use the switch to close the offscreen element, the switch does not reset to its off configuration. Furthermore, the offscreen element hides, then magically is shown again.

Use event delegation: $(document).on('click', '#offscreen-container', function() { ... }. jQuery will do the .is() check.

unfortunately, I don't need to monitor the clicks inside the offscreen-container. I need to monitor the clicks outside of the offscreen-container that are both, not the offscreen-toggle and are the offscreen-toggle. Because the offscreen-toggle will open and close the offscreen-container and will update the toggle itself for a visual 'on/off' effect. Clicks anywhere else, outside of the offscreen-container that are not on the offscreen-toggle, will close the offscreen-container and set the offscreen-toggle to its default 'off' state.

Working Solution
The following code worked for me and meets the requirements as specified in my question above. I just didn't expect that I would have to run a conditional to check if the element style is 'block'. I was under the impression that .toggle() would handle that bit for me. It worked that way when I wasn't trying to add additional functionality to click events controlling the offscreen element.
If someone knows a better way, please let me know.
jQuery
      $(document).on('click', (e) => {
        let t = $(e.target);

        // outside of offscreen container, but not the switch
        if (!t.is('#offscreen-container,#offscreen-container *') && !t.is('#offscreen-toggle')) {
          offscreenContainer.hide(1000);
          offscreenToggle.prop('checked', false);
        } else

        // outside of offscreen container, specifically the switch
        if (!t.is('#offscreen-container,#offscreen-container *') && t.is('#offscreen-toggle')) {
          if (offscreenContainer.get(0).style.display == 'block') {
            offscreenContainer.hide(1000);
            offscreenToggle.prop('checked', false);
          } else {
            offscreenContainer.toggle(1000);
          }
        }
      });

